# Where does the word 'Aranyam' (Sanskrit) derive from?

Tags: etymology, sanskrit, indian-languages

**Aranyam** basically means a forest / jungle.

Where does the word 'Aranyam' (Sanskrit) derive from?

**Background**
I searched online but couldn't find any references for the word except a [Hungarian word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aranyam) which is spelled similarly. I recently watched a [Project Shivoham video](https://youtu.be/NNi2OuO0oeE) on Youtube (the content seemed well-researched) where the content writer described the etymology of the word '*Aranyam*' as derived from a forest goddess by the name 'Arani'.

However, I suspect that the word is derived in relation to the root word '*ranam*' which means '*war*'. *Aranyam* being 'where you cannot do a war'.

Can any etymology / Sanskrit buffs shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in Monier-Williams' dictionary, *araṇya* (अरण्य) more generally means 'distant, foreign' and is derived from the verb r̩- 'go, move' etc. *Raṇa* 'battle' derives metaphorically from *ran ~ raṇ* 'rejoice'.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you point to the link?

Comment: I don't have a link, I have the dictionary. It was $20 in 1972.

Comment: @SriharshaC - Here's the link, see the rightmost column there: https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/csl-apidev/servepdf.php?dict=MW&page=86